# Using D3.js in my python program

Tags: python, html, math, d3.js, collatz

for a math project I am looking into the collatz conjecture, In my report I would like to alter the algorithm a little and have the tree as an image.

I have the code for the graph here

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550#flare.json

and the code for the algorithm is here (last line should have parenthesis)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Collatz-graph-20-iterations.svg

I am truly stuck, because I have no idea how to put the output onto the tree.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use D3js (or any other JavaScript library), at the minimum, you will have to create a simple HTML file which includes D3.js and any additional JS code for plotting your output.

You can use [this](http://bl.ocks.org/kristw/7eef5cb21f3dfc1c0a4c) as a starting point. If you're very new to JavaScript and need more information on how to proceed, let me know and I'll try to provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I have no experience with HTML or D3.js. I'm just looking for a way to stick my algorithm into a graph/tree.